# cscope how to get path path from environment variable

Tags: cscope

I have a cscope database path in environment variable CSCOPE_DB and vim works fine with it.
However, I would like cscope to also use this database when I use it without vim.

How can I do this ? I couldn't find any parameter that would allow me to specify path of the database so not sure how to do this.
I can cd to the database directory but I don't want to change my current directory when I exit cscope.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is how I solved it: //well still won't say this is the best way to do it.

Simple shell script:

```
#!/bin/csh
set ORIGINAL_PWD=`pwd`
cd $CSCOPE_DB
cscope -d
cd $ORIGINAL_PWD
```